# How to run a command as if it is called from cron

Tags: cron

I write a script and set it as a cron job.
But due to a difference of environment variables it doesn't work as it should be.

In that case I change a little bit with `crontab -e` and set a cron job time closest minute, and wait next minute to come to show the result. I feel this is a totally absurd approach, but I don't know better way to do it.

If there is a way to run a script as if it is called inside cron job, I'm going to use it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You could grab the environment from cron by scheduling `env` to run...

Comment: Related (1): [executing a sh script from the cron](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/executing-a-sh-script-from-the-cron/6794#6794)

Comment: Related (2): [Frustrating issue where neither cron nor su -c runs my job (permissions?)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31117/frustrating-issue-where-neither-cron-nor-su-c-runs-my-job-permissions/31120#31120)

Comment: Related (3): [Why does Crontab give me an error with my PHP script when running it from the terminal does not?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9880/why-does-crontab-give-me-an-error-with-my-php-script-when-running-it-from-the-te/9924#9924)

Comment: If you want to debug `cron`, just redirect the error output, run this with it `your_script.sh 2>/path/to/logfile`, that should help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do the other way around: forcing cron execution to use your login environment:

`bash -lc "your_command"`

From the bash manual:

```
-c string     If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.
              If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the
               positional parameters, starting with $0.
-l            Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
               (see INVOCATION below).
```

**INVOCATION** (a bit stripped):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

To known more:

- [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: Cron does not invoke the shell as a login shell when launching commands.

Comment: That's why forcing it with bash `-l` option.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you were saying. While this works, I wouldn't consider it a very elegant solution :-/

Comment: Sure. The elegant thing would be to tune whatever environment set for cron ...

Comment: Wouldn't `--norc` be closer to what `cron` runs?

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be:

```
/usr/bin/env --ignore-environment your command
```

From the manpage of `env`:

> `-i, --ignore-environment`
>
> start with an empty environment

Answer (score -1):

A better way is to use `at`.

Here are some examples

```
 echo $PWD/script.sh | at now
```

or

```
 echo "reboot" | at 5:00
```

or

```
 echo "mail -s test user@host" | at now + 1 hour
```

Here are some date/time [Examples](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/atdemo.htm)

Comment: I don't see the point here to play with `at`

Comment: @Ouki take a look at `/var/spool/cron/`

Comment: and it's POSIX also

Comment: `at` retains the working directory and environment at invocation, so it does not run as if from `cron`.